# .empty() method changes the number of results return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append, dom-manipulation

I'm extremely green to coding and need help with a technical issue. I'm using Ajax to submit a query that should return 10 results. It does that, however when I enter the empty method to clear the div that hold the results in order to submit a new query that is triggered by the event handler, it only displays one result instead of the ten.

I've ommited $(#returns).empty() to ensure that my code works and returns 10 results.

```
            url: queryURL,
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);

            var imageResults = response.data;

            for (var i=0; i<imageResults.length; i++){
                var gifDiv = $("<div id='returns'>");
                var rating = imageResults[i].rating;
                var ratingP = $("<p>").text("Rating: " + rating);
                // console.log(ratingP);
                var giph = $("<img>");
                var stillGiph = imageResults[i].images.fixed_width_small_still.url;
                giph.attr("src", stillGiph);  //Does the attribute need two arguments? Can I pass anim/still giphs in if statements separately? Does if statements for movement need to be a separate function?

                //empty returns div prior to appending new information
                $("#returns").empty();
                gifDiv.append(giph, ratingP);
                $("#returns").prepend(gifDiv);
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `$("#returns").empty();` before running the `for` loop. As it stands, your code does something roughly like

```
fetch 10 details then
    for detail in details
        empty returns div
        add an item
```

What you need is

```
fetch 10 details then
    empty returns div
    for detail in details
        add an item
```